# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'landmark'

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow, computer-vision, jupyter, opencv

I am on windows, using jupyter notebook, Mediapipe:Holistic Solution, Python, tensorflow.

I am using a Holistic solution and trying to get the left hand, right hand and pose landmarks. I am giving my webcam feed as input.

When I run the code below, there are no errors and everything is good.

After this, I was trying to check if I got the landmarks by using "results.left_hand_landmarks.landmark" and length of the landmarks using "len(results.left_hand_landmarks.landmark)" I am getting this "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'landmark'"

The funny part is the problem is only with left hand and right hand landmarks. I was able to get the Pose landmarks and its length. Please help.

```
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
# Set mediapipe model 
with mp_holistic.Holistic(min_detection_confidence=0.5, min_tracking_confidence=0.5) as holistic:
    while cap.isOpened():

        # Read feed
        ret, frame = cap.read()

        # Make detections
        image, results = mediapipe_detection(frame, holistic)
        print(results)
        
        # Draw landmarks
        draw_styled_landmarks(image, results)

        # Show to screen
        cv2.imshow('OpenCV Feed', image)

        # Break gracefully
        if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably didn't show your hands, so it was not registered and currently has its default value which is None. And just because of it you have pose landmarks.
So, to get rid of that error you just need to show your hands, so mediapipie managed to track them, and then you can display them.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Actually I felt the same way you did and tried multiple times to show my both hands to the webcam. And no luck. The issue still persists. My webcam's resolution is 720p HD. I don't know if that's the issue may be. But for some reason it doesn't track my hands. Please help.